# Enterprise scale BO Layer to SQL Server MAX Connections

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-design, architecture, n-tier-architecture

We have an application with approximately 60,000 client machines accessing it.  Previously we had a distributed model but we are moving to SaaS by creating a BO Layer and having calls come up into it over the WAN.  We use LINQ to Entities to access the database from the BO layer.  Our multi-tenant model is federated so that 'enterprises' comprising of multiple stores are on distinct sql servers (which usually has about 200 'enterprises' per server).

Each BO server is dual processor 8 core with HT (32 logicals).  IIS is setup to have 32 max worker processes.

The BO layer is working pretty well as each call pulls the connection string associated with that enterprise which then talks to the correct database.  The problem I am having though is that we have 1/4 of our clients on and about 15 BO servers, I have noticed that we have 3000+ open connections to each database server and its growing.

Any idea why it is growing like this?  What am I supposed to set where to make it re-use connections (connection pooling appears to be on) that will keep it from flooding each db server like this?  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It could be purely architecture thing.

How many database servers you have in total? And is the problem about workload is heavy on certain database servers but not others?

If that's the case, then probably considering how to partition different enterprise to different database servers will help. Or further partition data in heavy loaded database servers. Another technical is to vertical partition different tables for enterprises to different databases given no joins across vertical partitioned tables.

Comment: Hi Lex, the problem I am most worried about is just having too many open connections to the DB server and for that to start seriously impacting performance.  These are pretty beefy servers but we are approaching 5000+ open db connections now from all the BO servers.  I'm trying to figure out if architecturally there is a better way to approach this problem.

Comment: Then you might can consider using some caching solution, either caching locally or in a distributed cache grid. This could reduce DB connections by filtering some frequently accessed data.